# Iframe not loading site, what is wrong?

Tags: html, iframe

So I have been trying to have this little html site so I can monitor multiple pages.. but the iFrame isn't working. It works on every site for me that I try, I do know that google blocks their sites but I'm not using a google site, the url I'm trying to get to is:

http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Saint-Paul-MN/20313_rid/0-10000_price/0-37_mp/44.993637,-93.076086,44.885371,-93.222513_rect/12_zm/1_fr/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<iframe src="http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Saint-Paul-     MN/20313_rid/0-10000_price/0- 37_mp/44.993637,-93.076086,44.885371,-93.222513_rect/12_zm/1_fr/"width=“1000px” height=“1000px”>
</iframe>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The space in between the url isn't actually there if you see it, thats just the window size clipping it.

Comment: the spaces in the middle of url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page you are trying to embed into the iframe is telling the browser that it does not *want* to be embedded, by sending an [`X-Frame-Options: deny`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) HTTP response header.

You should also see a message in your browser console telling you that exactly that’s the case, and that the browser will therefor not display that page in any kind of (i)frame.

And there is nothing you can do about it, at least not client-side.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe said, with that set to deny there isn't anything that you can do to embed the site, if you have any experience with API's though, you could set up something through a call to that and have it displayed on your site. See: [Zillow API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm)